# Bootstrap 4 : Each row fill the same amount of height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a preloader and i'm struggling with the rows. I want my grey rectangle to be filled with 3 rows of 33% height.

Then I need:

- in the row 1, a svg logo
- in the row 2, a loader
- in the row 3, some text

Here's what I want:

[image]

Here's my code :

```css
#loader-modal {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    z-index: 100000;
}

.rectangle-chargement {
    width: 25%;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    left: 37.5%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
    border-radius: 0.15rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div id="loader-modal">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto rectangle-chargement">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!--<svg width="100%" >My SVG</svg>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" id="loader-circulaire">
                        <div id="chargement-loader"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <p class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto patienter-chargement">Veuillez patienter ...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you guys know a cleaner way to do it ? (and a working one of course)

Comment: Please provide a simplified stripped down version of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I can't, there is "a lot" of code because of the svg, nothing scary

Comment: Please separate your question from the context. In order to for us to help you we only need relevant code. I don't think the svg is required for this example.

Comment: the svg is my biggest problem ..

Comment: But my main question is : I have an absolute div, and in this div, 3 rows. How do I do 3 rows of same height filling the div (so 33% height each row) ?

Comment: A quick and dirty codepen: https://codepen.io/svenvandescheur/pen/KLBxKz?editors=1100. Simply, just specify percentages and make sure a base is available (which should be the case if the parent is positioned).  There multiple ways of doing this depending on the context but let's start with 33%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly hard code the heights, but since you ask if there is any cleaner way to do it, my opinion is to use *flexbox* with column flow direction, and let *flexbox* children grow by setting their `flex-grow` to 1.

This way doesn't require you to hard code the height for each row, and allows you to have as many rows as you "want".

```html
<div class="rectangle-chargement d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="rectangle-chargement-row flex-grow-1">
        Logo
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle-chargement-row flex-grow-1">
        Loader
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle-chargement-row flex-grow-1">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/sngkbLcq/32/

If you want to "centralize" the content in each row, you can mark each row as *flexbox* as well, and set its `justify-content` and `align-items` to center.

```html
<div class="rectangle-chargement d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="rectangle-chargement-row flex-grow-1 
        d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        Logo
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle-chargement-row flex-grow-1 
        d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        Loader
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle-chargement-row flex-grow-1 
        d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/sngkbLcq/36/

Comment: Perfect ! Thank's ;)